# Cannot start avd emulator on android studio 1.0 3

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I try launch emulator in android studio 1.0, but sending a error message![enter image description here, my O.S. is Ubuntu 14.04 x64][1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If you want develop android application in **android studio** must you need this thinks,

```
Latest SDK tools
Latest Build tools,
Latest Platform tools,
Latest API (SDK platform,System image(Based on system like x86 or 64))
Latest Android support repository
Latest support library
```

**Please check which system image your downloaded?**

**Option-1:**

```
If you already download google API download you must need google api system image
```

**Option-2**

```
Uninstall Android studio freshly download and install as power user.
```